# Internationalisation of a Django application

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'w writing a Django application, which stores data with descriptions in at least 2 languages (Russian and English).

By "data" I mean the information, which users will write (enter, edit) to and read from the application (not the UI). The application is sort of a documentation system - it contains documentation items (paragraphs), each of which has associated text in Russian, English and potentially other languages.

Is there a standard, established way to provide multi-language descriptions for data objects in Django? If yes, where is it described?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's support for localization and internationalization is limited to [translating text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) that is part of your labels and templates, [formatting of dates and numbers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/), and more recently proper support for [timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/). In addition, automatic URL prefixing of the preferred language was added in 1.4.

For storing user-entered content in multiple languages, there is no official support. However, projects like [`django-multilingual-model`](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-multilingual-model) are a good step in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is Django Hvad.

https://github.com/kristianoellegaard/django-hvad